# Getting an Uncaught TypeError: RulesModule.ruleModals is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In an effort to write some neat and clean JavaScript, I am trying my hand at Modules. I created this Rules Module:

```
//RulesModule.js
var RulesModule = (function () {

    return {

        checkModal: function () {
            var checkModalContents = // string contents

            return checkModalContents;
        },

        ruleModals: function (modalType) {
            switch (modalType) {
                case "CheckDateRule":
                    return checkModal();
                default:
                    return "UNKNOWN MODAL";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I then hook into the event of a dropdown element and when an option is selected we pass that option to the RulesModule.ruleModals method, to get the correct modal.

```
//EventSubscriptions.js
    var go = false;//switch off
    $('#rules').on('click', function () {//on click
    if (go) {//if go
            var selectedRule = $("#rules").find(":selected").val();

            var contents = RulesModule.ruleModals(selectedRule); // this line throws the error

            console.log(contents);
            $("#modalContents").empty(); // clear up contents
            $("#modalContents").append(contents);
            $("#myModal").css("display", "block");

        go = false;//switch off
    } else { go = true; }//if !go, switch on
}).on('blur', function () { go = false; });//switch off on blur
```

In my HTML, I load the two javascript files in my header:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title></title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/JavaScript/Modules/RulesModule.js"></script>
   <script src="~/JavaScript/EventSubscriptions.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return from `RulesModule` is an object and `checkModal` & `ruleModals` are two method to it,so try calling `checkModal` by `this.checkModal`

```js
var RulesModule = (function() {
  return {
    checkModal: function() {
      var checkModalContents = ''; // string contents
      console.log('Check Modal called')
      return checkModalContents;
    },
    ruleModals: function(modalType) {
      switch (modalType) {
        case "CheckDateRule":
          return this.checkModal();
        default:
          return "UNKNOWN MODAL";
      }
    }
  }
}());

console.log(RulesModule.ruleModals('CheckDateRule'))
```